# Mi programa en visual no puede leer un archivo txt cuando ejecuto el programa en otra pc

Tags: vb.net

Quisiera que mi programa en visual basic express 2010, al llevarlo a otra PC y ejecutarlo encuentre la ruta del archivo txt que quiero q lea, quisiera saber como referenciar la ruta para que sea leído en cualquier pc.

Actualmente utilizo esta linea de programa para ubicar el archivo txt:

```
Dim fichero As String = ".\listips.txt"
```

El problema es si llevo el ejecutable del programa a otra PC, tengo el archivo txt en una carpeta junto al ejecutable, pero al ejecutar el exe me sale error, porque no encuentra el archivo txt para leerlo.

Saludos
Agradecería su respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si el archivo de texto está en la misma carpeta que el del exe, solo tienes que conocer el `path` de la aplicación. Por ejemplo con la clase [Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) tienes el método [StartupPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Application_StartupPath)

```
Dim fichero As String = Application.StartupPath() & "\listips.txt"
```